# I have errors when trying to install material UI in my terminal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

$ npm install @material-ui/core

npm version : 6.14.4

error: Unrecognized token in source text.
At line:1 char:15

- $ npm install  <<<< @material-ui/core

  - CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnrecognizedToken

Comment: please post the entire traceback from the console

Comment: 17.0.2 is the version

Comment: yeah, it have the same error but the guy below method works

Comment: Try using external Terminal (CMD)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with quotes:

```
npm install "@material-ui/core"
```

Explanation:

You've got the error because the @ is making PowerShell treat @angular2-material as a variable

Comment: @Briton are you useing PowerShell ?

Comment: Depending of the shell, characters like `@` can be interpreted differently.